# Django can't migrate after cloning repository

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, database-migration

I've been working on a Django app on another machine, with a local postgis database. I pushed the entire thing to GitHub, except what is in the .gitignore.

**.gitignore**

```
venv
*.pyc
staticfiles
.env
.idea
uploads
```

Came home and cloned the repo, installed all the requirements and created a new local Postgres database with the same settings from settings.py and the same PostGIS extension.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

But I can't create any migrations. I just get an error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "something_something" does not exist
```

I have tried rolling back to the first initial migration file, but with the same result.

```
makemigrations applabel 0001
```

It is as if Django think it is still the same database, but with all the tables missing. But I can't migrate and get Django to create them.

How can I get out of this mess? Can I for a migrate somehow?

If you need additional information, that I've left out please ask.

Comment: Have you tried `makemigration` after `migrate --fake`

Comment: Great suggestion. I just tried running `migrate --fake` and `migrate --fake-initial`still throws me that error.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have no idea on your repo to experiment around and Answer it specifically. What I can think of is as below

1. Use `migrate --fake` (as mentioned in the comment)
2. Try changing host entry from localhost to `127.0.0.1`.
3. Create a role (user) in psql with necessary permissions and use them in `settings`.
4. Check for port permissions.

Please note this is just guesses.

Answer (score 0):

```
go on the project directory and comment all the apps, on settings and urls minus the app the has error, you now what is because the table name is the name of the model
```

1. run makemigratios and  migrate
2. retire the commet and run the things, do it one per one